# Exclude timestamp from being rendered in asciidoc/asciidoctor

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Is it possible to exclude/suppress the timestamp from being generated in `asciidoc`/`asciidoctor`? Its the "Last updated..." footer at the bottom of the page.

P.S I am trying to do this in `asciidoctor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to redefine template that generates the "Last ..." message. Create a new file `nofooter.conf` with the following content:

```
[footer-text]
<single space on this line>
```

And then use the following command to make HTML:

```
asciidoc -f nofooter.conf file.txt
```

It should produce empty `<div id="footer-text"></div>`.

**UPD.** For `asciidoctor` it's possible to specify attribute `nofooter`:

```
asciidoctor -a nofooter file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Andrey. but as per my latest edit, `asciidoctor` [does not support configuration files](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#configuration-files) :(

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:nofooter:` document attribute](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/attributes/document-attributes-ref/#:%7E:text=PDF%20converter%20only.-,nofooter,-empty).